# When should we use groups in our regex? What is the real advantage here?

Tags: python, regex

I have two regex. Both matches American Date Formats. Here there are (I highlight the group I talk about):

```
^(.*?)((0|1)?\d)-((0|1|2|3)?\d)-**(19|20\d\d)**(.*?)$

^(.*?)((0|1)?\d)-((0|1|2|3)?\d)-**((19|20)\d\d)**(.*?)$
```

Both matches:

```
asasa12-12-1993.txt
asassa12-12-2010.txt
```

In the book he put 19|20 into its own group. Why?

Comment: I think the `**` is not a valid notation. Note that you can also write `([0-3])?` using a character class instead of an alternation `(0|1|2|3)?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AKX is almost right but it's more than that.

`19|20\d\d` will match either `19` OR `20 followed by 2 digits`.

**But it will not match `19 followed by 2 digits`.**

Have a look here: https://regex101.com/r/lvYGUb/3

You'll see 2010 is a single match whereas 19 is matched alone, without the `93`, and as a consequence the 93 goes with the `.txt` group, which is probably not what you want

In a similar way, consider this data file :

```
20 euros
20 €
```

Let's say you want to match 100% of both lines using a regex.

`\d+ euros|€` won't work because it means either `a number followed by the word euros` OR `just the € sign alone`

But

`\d+ (euros|€)` will work

So the purpose of the parentheses here is not capturing the group, they are just meant to put a boundary to the OR operator.

If you don't want those parentheses to capture the group, you can add `?:` to make it a non-capturing group, like so:

```
^(.*?)((0|1)?\d)-((0|1|2|3)?\d)-((?:19|20)\d\d)(.*?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is it's easier for humans to parse.

The first (`(19|20\d\d)`) doesn't make it obvious whether the alternation is "`19` or `20\d\d`", whereas in `((19|20)\d\d`) it's obvious to see it's "`19` or `20`, then `\d\d`".

Comment: That's a perfect explanation AKX. Thanks!